# Как вы бекапите ваши андроид проекты?

Tags: android-studio

Одним из советов сообщества было "делать бекапы проектов", а вот куда и как сказано не было. Я сделал то что первое пришло на ум, ключ и проект я засунул в зашифрованный архив и отправил в drive.google.com

А как бекапите вы?

Comment: Github, Bitbucket?

Comment: Мы используем системы контроля версий

Comment: @s8am , а на github возможен приватный репозиторий?

Comment: На Bitbucket есть приватные free-репозитории , на Github только в платных аккаунтах

Comment: Возможен, но платно (я в своем комментарии не просто так написал два сервиса, ибо во втором имеется возможность создания приватных репозиториев бесплатно).